# Excel Formula compare match multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare, match

I am very stuck on this problem i have attached an image to explain better - i need to check Column B Title and Find all Exact Matching values from other Columns C D E F (attributes) and give an output
In Column H I J K - in order to find out which sku has which attributes

it took me 2 days to organise the attributes but I am so confused as to how to get the result I need -putting little mockup of what I am trying to acheive but the actual file contains 30000 skus and titles and 60 attributes to look for

I have been checking tutorials since last 2 days but cant find any that do what i need to

Any help will be most appreciated -
[image: mockup of worksheet]

UPDATE
I realised I wont be able to get the desired results I need in full doing it the way showing in the previous pic so please check new image of how it is now and how I need it to be - I tried using Find and Highlight all of the same text but I get 2 issues. 1. It was selecting for example Weight 500g and Weight per piece 5g together when I need then to be in separate columns when I tried to do find by Weight.  2. is after all values are found I cant copy those cells to paste into a new sheet   get  This action wont work on multiple selections error message.

[image: New mockup of desired result]

Comment: If u want to find matching values in your sheet, use conditional formating.

Comment: `I need to check Column B Title...`. How? Where are you checking this title? Why does SKU A001 have color = Red in column E but then color = White in column J? Are columns A:F your data, and then you are trying to do something in columns G:K? This question is not yet clear.

Comment: col H - K is mockup of the output i want C D E F are the attributes im searching for in the title COL B  - in the title for sku A001 White so in J2 white is shown because Match was found in COL B using the The attribute values in COL E

Comment: ... based on what?

Comment: @jt9489 refer the solution I have posted that should be working for you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, this should work for you, if I have understood your query correctly,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=IF($G2="","",IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH(" "&C$2:C$5&" "," "&$B2&" "),C$2:C$5),""))
```

Fill Down & Fill Right !!!

Note: Color Column `E` has no Black Color so its not showing in output column `J`.

Comment: thank you mayukh i forgot to add the Black as you noticed - i will check in main file and update

Comment: @jt9489 is it resolved now or is it still pending, can you let us know ?

Comment: @ Mayukh the formula kindly provided is correct and works in mockup but when im trying same in main file not getting any results only difference is G2 in mockup in Main file is BK2 and there are 60 Attributes Names and Max Attributes values for any single Attribute Name is 221 I'm entering like this in BL2 `=IF($BK2="","",IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH(" "&C$2:C$221&" "," "&$B2&" "),C$2:C$221),""))`   If I use same title and SKU and Attribute Names and Values in Mockup and its working correct

Comment: I need to see the workbook, is it possible to share a one drive link so I can help you with the solution. Also if its feasible for you to show the expected output there manually.

Comment: @ Mayukh thanks for the reply is it possible to pm me here please

Comment: I finally figured out why alot of attributes were not working its because there were extra spaces at the end trailing spaces which I removed will test in more detail and update here

Comment: Hi Mayukh did you get chance to see the updated question?

Comment: Just saw the notification. Will update the solution again

Comment: Mayukh solutions works great for the first part of the original question before the update was added Thank you really apprecaite it